# What is the workflow of installing and using any js/css library using npm in laravel 8?

Tags: laravel, npm, laravel-8, libraries, laravel-mix

What is the workflow of installing and using **any js/css** library using npm in laravel 8. What steps should I follow?

For an example let's say I want to install `fontawesome` using npm and use it in my `laravel` project. What I know is, once I run the `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free` command it creates a folder for that inside `node_modules`.
I don't know what should I do after `npm install --save @fortawesome/fontawesome-free`.

How can I get to know what to do inside `resources/css/app.css` and `webpack.mix.js` and what next for any `js` or `css` library?

Comment: Do you have any updates to this question? Have you achieved installing css/js library using nmp?

Comment: A suggestion would be installing Laravel-Mix. Analytical steps can be found [here](https://github.com/laravel-mix/laravel-mix/blob/bc9063b808bf2689936222469c160b9f8d1f6838/docs/installation.md). Feel free to ask and share with us if you have already found something else that works.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use laravel mix, based on my experience the general step to use any css / js package from npm to laravel mix is :

1. npm install.
2. import the css needed by the library to `resources/sass/app.scss`
3. require js script needed by the library to `resource/js/bootstrap.js`
4. `npm run development` or `npm run production` to rebuild the app.css and bootstrap.js.

For fontawesome you can read further in this tutorial:

https://dev.to/dendihandian/adding-font-awesome-to-laravel-the-laravel-mix-way-4ndj